# What is the study of relations that aren't function?

Tags: terminology, relations

Is there an accepted term for a relation that is not a function? Is this a field on it's own with importance?

Comment: Not quite sure what youre asking. The word "relation" is general, and need not be a function.  You might find a discussion on relations in an abstract algebra course or set theory or something along those lines.

Comment: To expound upon @CogitoErgoCogitoSum’s remark, examples of general relations include equalities among mathematical objects of any kind, inequalities, equivalence, congruence, belonging to a set—the list goes on and on, transcending separate fields. Really, mathematical disciplines define relations on their own as the need arises.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum  I am asking if the set of relations minus the set of functions has a name and study.  Analogy, real numbers minus the set of algebraic numbers is called the set of transcendental numbers.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I a not sure if that is true. I would think that there are statements that would be true about all relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order theory is an important study of a class of relations that are not functions.